# leap year regular expression

Tags: regex

My task is to write a regular expression which accept leap-year only, and the first year have to be 1584 without upper limit. Could someone help me with redo this expr. ?

```
(15(8[48]|9[26]))|((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048]))|(([2468][048]|16|3579[26])00)
```

It doesn't work, i did it:

```
(15(8[48]|9[26]))|((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048]))|(([2468][048]|16|3579[26])00)|
(
    [1-9]\d*
    (
        ([02468][048]|[13579][26])00
        |
        \d\d(0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])
    )
)
```

and to 9996 It works but when I add 1 It doesn't accept 19996, or 100000000 or higher, did I do something wrong ?

for example it doesn't work for 109400

Comment: What doesn't work with this regex?

Comment: It's hard to come up with a tool that would be worse for this task than regex.

Comment: Maybe a screwdriver would be worse, but I am unsure...

Comment: See my edit. Add at the end of your regex in a lone line.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex matches leap year from 1584 until 9996.

To math leap years greater than 9996, just add this alternative at the end of the regex:

```
|
(
    [1-9]\d*
    (
        ([02468][048]|[13579][26])00
        |
        \d\d(0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])
    )
)
```

@user2010564 : add this in a lone line at the end of your regex:

```
|([1-9]\d*(([02468][048]|[13579][26])00|\d\d(0[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])))
```

Comment: Uh, no. There's a gap between 10000 and 11580 (and between 20000 and 21580 etc.) :)

Comment: It still doesn't match 10000, 20000 etc.; I think you need `[1-9]\d*` instead of  `\d+` and `[02468]` instead of the first `[2468]`. Also, you forgot the brackets around `13579` in that line.

Comment: Yay! Kind of proves @dasblinkenlight's point that regex is not the right tool for this, doesn't it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Sure, it doesn't :-)

Comment: Could you write it like you think you should be ?

Comment: @user2010564: Convert the year to an integer, then apply this simple [leap year algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm).